# I/O operation on closed csv file

Tags: python, csv, io

I have some information in a `.csv` file. I want to be able to check whether the file has a certain code inside.

This is my code below:

```
import csv
with open('bezoekerscode.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)


def code_control():
    code = str(input('Type hier uw code in die u wilt controleren:\n'))
    if code in reader:
        print('code komt overheen, en wordt nu gecheckt of de aanbieder wel correct is.')
        f.close()
    else:
        print('deze code komt niet overheen.')
        f.close()

code_control()
```

What should come out of this is either:

- Code matches

  or
- Code doesn't match

Comment: You have two problems here: First, you incorrectly use `with` which will close `f` at the end of the context, leaving the `csv.reader` without a valid input file. Second, you incorrectly use `csv.reader` which will give you *rows* of items, not the items directly; you have to check that `code` is in any row, otherwise you check whether it is *equal* to any row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact an empty list `[]` in Python is evaluated as `False` in an `if` clause:

```
if [line for line in reader.readlines() if code in line.strip()]:
    # if code doesn't match a line, it will return [] ergo false
    # and else is going to get executed.
else: 
    # Do else stuff.
```

You generally want to move your `with open` statement into the function too. `with` will automatically close your file afterwards. Your code would be better of looking like this:

```
import csv

def code_control():
    with open('bezoekerscode.csv', 'r') as f:
         reader = csv.reader(f)
         code = str(input('Type hier uw code in die u wilt controleren:\n'))
        if [line for line in reader.readlines() if code in line.strip()]::
            print('code komt overheen, en wordt nu gecheckt of de aanbieder wel correct is.')
    else:
        print('deze code komt niet overheen.')

code_control()
```

---

Note, you ***cannot*** perform operations on a closed file. To evaluate if a file is still open you can check its `file.closed` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you are using the **reader** variable inside that **code_control** function, but the variable is local in the with **context**.

You could either declare it globally, or send it as a parameter to the code_control function as such:

```
import csv

def code_control(reader):
    code = str(input('Type hier uw code in die u wilt controleren:\n'))
    if code in reader:
        print('code komt overheen, en wordt nu gecheckt of de aanbieder wel correct is.')
    else:
        print('deze code komt niet overheen.')

with open('bezoekerscode.csv', 'r') as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f)
   code_control(reader)
```

Also you don't really need f.close() because the context manager you are using through **with** handles that already.

Comment: Thank you, this worked! However, we have a .csv file with some code information inside. One of the cells has a code (for example "A44"). When I try "if "a44" in reader:, it says it the code cannot be found.

Comment: **reader** is not local to the context - a context does not have its own scope. However, the context will close **f** at its end, which breaks the reader (as it requires an *open* file).

Comment: Thanks @MisterMiyagi, I didn't knew that contexts don't have their own scope. And in this case it behaved as a local variable so I assumed it was, but it seems I have to do some more reading.